# Capture some object and create 3d photo

Tags: android, 3d, modeling, 360-degrees

I want to create a 3d view (360 degree view) for an object captured using camera like the apps [*Fyuse*](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fyusion.fyuse) or [*Phogy*](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vivoti.phogy) doing it. I researched on this but did not found something useful to start with.

I have some questions like:

1. What tool should I use for this e.g unity or Android Studio is enough?
2. Should I use any sdk (like Rajawali for 3d modeling) and some other tool to accomplish this or can this be implemented without using any third party sdk?
3. Can this be implemented by capturing a video of object and then extracting its frames and then combining them to show 360 degree view?

Can anyone please guide me on this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

In fact, those apps are not really 3D.

You can get similar results by recording a video together with information from motion / pose sensor so you can assign a cellphone pose to every frame.
Then you can control the playback in respect to actual cellphone rotation.

This project might help you: https://github.com/e-lab/VideoSensors

Comment: Thanks @ni1ight for quick responce. I will give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: this is a great answer, please moderator do not delete this answer